# Ubuntu Touch and CARDDAV

Tags: sync, calendar

I have been trying to sync contacts and calendar events from an own cloud instance to an Aquaris 4.5 running ubuntu touch. I've searched the web and found a number of examples for  using syncevolution but I was not able to transfer the infos given to my particular setup.

First off: I do not know the database names on the local device - it seems that the names have been translated into German after I chose German as the system languages, resulting in a Calendar name of "Persönlich" - including the Umlaut-o. I've managed to sync calendar events once, but when adding setups for CardDAV the calendar setup seized to work.

In order to start another try, I would need to know what the names of the local databases are against which I will have to run a sync. In addition a bit of enlightenment concerning the syntax of syncevolution would be much appreciated.

I ran a sync of calendar events with --replace-from-server - or something to that effect (I'd have to look up the syntax now and my phone battery is currently empty) and the events on my owncloud server were deleted as a consequence. It seems that my notion of who is the server and who is the client were not correct. That should show you the level of my experience...

Thanks in advance for any helpful hints

Comment: For caldav client, server is client & client is server. Hence `refresh-from-server` will delete everything from server. Here remote-local concept is more accurate than server-client. A better option is `refresh-from-remote`.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/

Comment: Please provide steps you have taken or commands you have run to setup syncevolution. Provide this info on http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I have pasted command line arguments which I issued on the phone. When running a slow sync afterwards, calendar events got transferred from the owncloud instance to the phone.

Comment: Pasted? where? Link?  You can also use `two-way` sync after first sync.

Comment: I have used the link to paste.ubuntu.com that you provided.

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com is the website. when you paste some thing in it and click paste, it will generate a link, like .......http://paste.ubuntu.com/11374848/.  (Notice the random number at the end). Provide me that link. Thanks